# Why is there no meta for each question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, meta

It really bothers me when a comment on a question is not about the question itself but some meta discussion like whether it should have a tag or not. I think it would be best to have some kind of metacomment for each question that could be displayed at a slightly different place than the other comments, or maybe they could have another color, or an option to hide them. What are the pros and cons?

Comment: Why is the existence of that comment so bothersome? And why would making it more prominent be *less* bothersome?

Comment: You've tagged this as a feature request, the onus is on you to provide the pros

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We don't need anything as permanent as a meta question for things like the tags a question should have etc.

These are transient things and once the problem has been sorted out, can and should be deleted.

Meta questions should be reserved for something more substantial - whether the question should be reopened etc.